# Classes of groups known to be realizable (IGP)

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, big-list

A finite group $G$ of order $n$ is said to be realizable (over $\mathbb{Q}$) if there exists a Galois extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})=G$. I'm curious what classes of groups are known to be realizable?

Shafarevich proved that solvable groups are realizable. Thus the following results "nontrivially" imply realizability:

> If $n$ is odd, $G$ is solvable.
>
> If $n$ has prime factorization $n=\prod p_i$, then $G$ is solvable.
>
> If $n$ is of the form $p^\alpha q^\beta$ where $p,q$ are prime and $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$, $G$ is solvable.

It is worthwhile to point out that:

> If $G_1,\ldots,G_m$ are solvable then so is $G_1 \times \cdots \times G_m$.

What other classes are known to be realizable? I've googled on it but can't find a big list or whatever.

(The smallest group I've found through Groupprops not to be immediately identifiable as realizable is $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{F}_5)$.)

Edit: If no one objects I'll continuously update this question whenever I find something interesting.

Comment: This is a problem of inverse Galois theory. I know nothing about inverse problems, but I'm fairly sure that it is an inappropriate tag. Taking the liberty of retagging a fine question. I am half-expecting somebody to give a link to a MO-question soon :-)

Comment: It's inverse GT, yes, hence an inverse problem. I don't get it :)

Comment: Have you (or I?) read the tag wiki of inverse problems. I think that *inverse-problems* form a class of analytical problems. That's kinda restrictive, but if analysts want to keep that game (or name) to themselves, I'm not gonna argue.

Comment: Dear Erik, Are you sure that $SL(2,\mathbb F_p)$ is known to be realizable as a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ for large values of $p$?  This contradicts the statement [here](http://galoisrepresentations.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/inverse-galois-problem/), for example.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE I double-checked my reference and noticed my error: The precise statement is that for the case $SL(m,F_q)$ there exist extensions $\mathbb{Q} \subset K \subset L$ s.t $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian and $L/K$ is Galois with $SL(m,F_q)$ as its group. Thanks for noticing my mistake.

Comment: Dear Erik, Thanks for your reply. Now that I know I'm not confused about a key example, I'll try to write an answer to your question.  (Not now, but in a day or so.) Regards,